# Getting Ordered TextField Data From Dynamically Created Cells in Swift (3.1) Table View

Tags: swift, tableview, textfield, uitableview

I am trying to figure out how to get textfield data from cells in a tableview in an ordered fashion. So far I am able to type into each textfield a retrieve the type data. To do so in the correct order though the user must edit the first cell...last cell, any other way and the data isn't in the correct order.

For Example:

I have the program create 5 cells with a textfield,

- textfield1: I typed here second
- textfield2: I typed here fourth
- textfield3: I typed here first
- textfield4: I typed here fifth
- textfield5: I typed here third

the way I currently have it my dataArray would look identical to this one, because it is being stored based on when it is typed in and not the order of the cells.
I would like to type the above example, but my data come out like this:

- textfield1: I typed here first
- textfield2: I typed here second
- textfield3: I typed here third
- textfield4: I typed here fourth
- textfield5: I typed here fifth

Here is my textfield editing code:

```
@IBAction func TitleEditBegin(_ sender: UITextField) {
}

@IBAction func TitleEditEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
    print(sender.tag) // Debug
    titleArray.append(sender.text!)
}
```

I know for the time being that any other changes will be appended to the titleArray, but I want to solve the ordering issue first.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I forgot to add in how I am creating the cells, the code is below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = TitleSessionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TitleSessionCell

    cell.SessionTitleLabel.text = "Title"
    // cell.SessionTitleField.text = "Default"
    cell.SessionTitleField.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.SessionTitleField.delegate = self
    print(indexPath.row) // Debug

    return cell

}
```

**EDIT 2:** Adding where I define the text fields.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TitleSessionCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var SessionTitleField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SessionTitleLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a dictionary I believe. I would assign all of the textFields a different tag. So for textField1 you would say `textField1.tag = 1`. I don't see the creation of your text fields, so it is hard to show the best way of adding that in, but then after handling that, I would create the dictionary as a class variable.

```
var textFieldDictionary: [Int: String] = [:]
```

and then add in the text to it like so:

```
if sender.text != nil && sender.text != "" {
    textFieldDictionary[sender.tag] = sender.text
}
```

then when you want to retrieve the information, do something like this:

```
for i in 0..<biggestTextFieldNumber {
    if let text = textFieldDictionary[i] {
        //do something with text
        print(text)
    }
}
```

or you could just grab the specific number values out whenever you needed them by using:

```
textFieldDictionary[numberYouWant]
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: My problem right now though, is that whichever textfield is edited first is given the sender.tag = 0. So once that occurs everything else goes out of whack. Is there a way to call the cell to get it's tag?

Comment: can you post you cellForRow function

Comment: Whatever cell is editted first is not given sender.tag = 0 unless you also set the tag for the text field somewhere else. What you are doing is placing the text in the array based on which text field is entered first. If you do as I said then this won't be the case, because no matter when you store the information it is retrieved by a value rather than by a position in its group type.

Comment: So since my cells are dynamically created I would write a loop to create those text field tags? The text fields are created in a table view cell class.

Comment: I added the class where the text field is defined.

Comment: You already are setting the tags to indexPath.row. The only way that this code is giving them the wrong Int is if you have more than one section in the tableView. Elsewise they with all be unique and identical to the row they are in.

Comment: but I don't see how that helps me get the individual data in the correct order into the title array. I assure you that if I don't type in order the way I want the titleArray it does not come out in the correct order.